# ROC curve from a list of p-values

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, roc

Does it make sense to express a list of p-values as a ROC curve?

Suppose we have $N$ independent null hypotheses tested, with $p_i $ the corresponding $p$-values. For convenience, we assume that the null hypotheses are ordered from smaller to larger $p_i $. Let us also define $\bar p_i = 1-p_{N-i}$. We can build a classifier with parameter $k$ such that each hypothesis is classified as "accepted" if $p_i>k $ or "rejected" if otherwise. We could use the Benjamini-Hochberg (BH) procedure for controlling the FDR to estimate the ROC curve of the accepted/rejected classifier. To that end, let $q_r$ be the estimated FDR, according to BH, where $r$ is the largest $i$ such that $p_i\leq k$. From $r$ and $q_r$ we can get an estimate of the numbers of true positives and false positives. To estimate the numbers of true negatives and false negatives we can follow the same procedure with $\bar p_i$. Having estimates for the numbers of true positives, false positives, true negatives, and false negatives, we can build a ROC curve straighforwardly.

This procedure seems very natural to me. However, I have never seen it, so I am wondering if it makes any sense.

Comment: I don't see where this provides estimates for the # of false positives or # of false negatives. If you had that information what would be the point of the hypothesis test in the first place other than to determine the validity of a certain procedure? Furthermore, why don't you just use a single numeric value to convey that information if you have it?

Comment: @Josh A key aspect here is multiple hypothesis testing. Also, it is important the distinction between hypothesis testing and classification. BH provides estimates of the false discovery rate (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini.E2.80.93Hochberg_procedure)). From $r=FP+TP$ and $q_r = FP/(FP+TP)$ we can solve for the estimated number of false positives (FP) and true positives (TP), where $q_r$ is the BH estimate at level $r$. Similarly, from $\bar q_r$ on can solve for FN and TN. All these estimates are a function of $k\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Josh Namely, the alternative is not a single numeric value, but an entire list of $p$-values adjusted for multiple testing.